# Difference between passing ActivityName.this and passing this when we need to pass context

Tags: java, android

I have seen a convention in android programming, that when forexample calling another activity from some activity:

```
Intent i=new Intent(Caller.this,Called.class);
startActivity(i);
```

My question is why we write `Caller.this` instead of just writing `this`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need `Caller.this` if you are inside an inner class.

For example:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i=new Intent(Caller.this, Called.class);
    startActivity(i);
  }
};
```

Here, `this` is not an instance of `Caller`, but rather an instance of an anonymous inner class inheriting from `View.OnClickListener`. To get to the "outer" `this`, you prefix it with the outer class name (i.e., `Caller.this`).

Answer (score 3):

If you are inside your activity class and want to refer to it then you use `this`. But when you are already inside a class (for example Anonymous class) inside your activity class, then you cannot use `this` keyword as it refers to that Anonymous class. However, in such cases you need to write for e.g. `Activity.this` to refer to your activity's instance